# Options for using this electrical box to add new outlet above

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am trying to add a recessed outlet above this electrical box and was planning on just tying into this one. Looks like there are no knockouts in the back I can use and the other side of the wall looks the same.

Am I SOL without replacing the electrical box?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's actually an option to `Delete` right next to the `Edit` link, @RobertChapin... Just hover & it appears

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, if you can't work the angle for drilling a hole per Robert Chapin's answer—since the box appears to be fairly deep—the box can simply be replaced.  You should be able to use a sawzall or oscillating tool with a metal-cutting blade, and cut the mounting nails at the top and bottom.  You can replace it with either an old work box (with the screw tabs), or a New/Old work box, like the Carlon B125AB.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bakelite box.  You can drill through the top or bottom near the back and feed cable through the holes you make there.

See [How can I bring cable into a junction box with no knockouts?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257641/how-can-i-bring-cable-into-a-junction-box-with-no-knockouts)